# Why does my circuit breaker threshold affect QoS 1 in MQTT?

Tags: python, mqtt, distributed-system, paho, circuit-breaker

I'm currently working on a distributed systems course in python and javascript and trying to use some fault tolerance in my code, in particular QoS 1 and the circuit breaker pattern. I have 3 components and they send messages by publishing and subscribing to topics using Paho-MQTT. The first component generates and publishes random origin and destination coordinates, the second component calls an external API in order to retrieve travel information for these coordinates and other filter functions and the third visualises this.

My problem is that the third component stops receiving any more messages after 19 messages and then proceeds to receive duplicates for all 19 if the circuit breaker threshold is set to 5. I assume this has something to do with PUBACK acknowledgements for QoS 1.

**Question**
If I change the circuit breaker threshold to 2, then it works perfectly fine without stopping and sending only duplicates. Does anyone know why this happens?

**Code**
In the second component, I have used a circuit breaker to drop incoming messages when the queue is full with the failure threshold at 5. The Paho client in this component subscribes to topics with QoS 0:

```
from queue import Queue
from circuitbreaker import circuit

queue = Queue(50)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.subscribe([(subscribe_topic, 0), (subscribe_topic_external, 0)])

@circuit(failure_threshold=5, recovery_timeout=15)
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    message = json.loads(msg.payload)
    queue.put(message, block=True, timeout=1)
```

After the data goes through the API and other filter functions, it is published using QoS 1:

```
while True:
    if not queue.empty():
        trip_request = queue.get()
        trip = pipe.transfer_data(trip_request)
        client.publish(publish_topic, json.dumps(trip), qos=1)
```

The third component then subscribes also using QoS 1 and handles duplicates in the on message:

```
client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log("connected");
  client.subscribe(topic, {qos: 1});
})

client.on('message', (topic, message, packet) => {
  let tripRequest = JSON.parse(message.toString())
  let requestId = tripRequest.requestId
  if (tripSet.has(requestId)) {
    console.log("Duplicate trip request found. Request ID: " + requestId)
  } else {
    tripSet.add(requestId)
    queue.push(JSON.parse(message.toString()));
  }
});
```

Comment: You should not do blocking calls in the `on_message` callback

Comment: @hardillb Thanks for the reply! Do you mean this line: `queue.put(message, block=True, timeout=1)` ? If so, I needed the block so that it can throw an exception since this is what the circuit breaker recognises as failures. Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: Probably, stopping `on_message` running is going to break the Paho library since this is run on the paho network thread, and as such it won't handle the QOS handshakes properly. As such the broker will try to redeliver.

Comment: @hardillb Sorry, I just realised that I left out a small but important detail. The Paho client in the second component subscribes to the topic using QoS 0 where I'm blocking the `on_message`. The problem occurs between publishing in the second component and subscribing in the third.